# perl6 How to match a character only under some conditions?

Tags: regex, match, conditional-statements, raku

I have a file in the format:

```
- foo bar - baz
  one two three - or four
  and another line

- next job
  do this - and that
```

and my grammar is

```
grammar tasks {
    regex TOP        { \n* <oneTask>+ \n* }
    regex oneTask    { ^^ \- (<oneSection> <endSection>)+ }
    regex oneSection { \N+ } # this is not quite working
    regex endSection { \n+ }
```

}

in the regex oneSection, how do I code the fact that "I want to match a '-' only when it is not at the beginning of a line"?

I put the file into a string and parse this string:

```
my $content = slurp("taskFile");
my $result = tasks.parse($content);
```

This is not quite working.

```
<[\N] - [\-]> does not make the match conditional.
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easier to put down what you want to match rather than try to exclude something.

What you are looking for is one character at the start of a line that is not a newline or a dash, followed by any number of not newlines. Or you are looking for at least one character that is not a newline that does not come after a newline.

```perl6
regex oneSection {

    || ^^            # beginning of line
       <-[\n-]>      # not newline or dash
       \N*           # any number of not newlines

    || <!before ^^>  # check the position before this is not the start of a line
       \N+

}
```

(This is so complex because you are trying to put the complexity in the wrong spot in the grammar)

---

You could also match like you are currently and add a test that fails if it starts with a `-`.

```perl6
regex oneSection {
    \N+

    <!{ # fail if the following is True
        $/.starts-with('-')
    }>
}
```

---

A Grammar is a type of Class and a Regex/Token/Rule is a type of Method. So you should probably be writing them that way by adding newlines and comments.

Writing grammars gets much nicer if you learn how to use the `%` and `%%` regex operators.
( the difference is `%%` can match a trailing separator )

Using `%` effectively can take some getting used to, so I am going to show you how I would have used it to match your file.

I also changed the separator of the sections from just a newline to a newline and two spaces. This will remove the spaces from what a `section` matches, which will simplify any further processing.

While you are learning I would recommend using Grammar::Debugger and Grammar::Tracer.

```perl6
grammar Tasks {
    # use token for its :ratchet behaviour
    # ( more performant than regex because it doesn't backtrack )
    token TOP {
        \n*       # ignore any preceding empty lines

        <task>+   # at least one task
        %         # separated by
        \n+       # at least one newline

        \n*       # ignore trailing empty lines
    }

    token task {
      ^^ '- '     # a task starts with ｢- ｣ at the beginning of a line

      <section>+  # has at least one section
      %           # separated by
      "\n  "      # a newline and two spaces
    }

    token section { \N+ }
}
```

```perl6
my $test = q:to/END/;
- foo bar - baz
  one two three - or four
  and another line

- next job
  do this - and that
END

put Tasks.parse( $test, :actions(class {
  method TOP     ($/) { make @<task>».made.List }
  method task    ($/) { make @<section>».made.List }
  method section ($/) {
    make ~$/  # don't do any processing, just make it a Str
  }
})).made.perl;

# (("foo bar - baz", "one two three - or four", "and another line"),
#  ("next job", "do this - and that"))
```

If I had put `use Grammar::Tracer;` at the top this is what it would output:

```perl6
TOP
|  task
|  |  section
|  |  * MATCH "foo bar - baz"
|  |  section
|  |  * MATCH "one two three - or four"
|  |  section
|  |  * MATCH "and another line"
|  * MATCH "- foo bar - baz\n  one two three - or four\n  and another l"
|  task
|  |  section
|  |  * MATCH "next job"
|  |  section
|  |  * MATCH "do this - and that"
|  * MATCH "- next job\n  do this - and that"
|  task
|  * FAIL
* MATCH "- foo bar - baz\n  one two three - or four\n  and another line"
```

That `FAIL` is expected because there was a trailing newline and it could be followed by a task as far as the grammar knows.

Comment: Very nice !!! Thank you so much, Brad Gilbert !!! I hope other readers can really benefit from your answers; I certainly learned much from you. Thank you professor :-)

Answer (score 1):

Match anything that's not the start of the string, followed by a dash

```
[^$]-
```

Comment: Thank you Andy Ray ! But how to generalize to a universal conditional of match? E.g., match "-" only when it is the nth line and only if the total number of "-" has not exceeded k?